# How to use reflection to cast a control as its type in order to modify properties?

Tags: c#, list, reflection, properties, controls

Here's an example of what I currently do:

```
book enable = false;
foreach (Control c in controlList)
{
    if (c is MyTextBox)
    {
        (c as MyTextBox).Enabled = enable;
    }
    if...
    ...
}
```

Instead of having multiple if statements for every type of control, is there a way to get the type of the control in order to cast and then be able to access and set a property of that control?

Comment: Enabled is a property of the base Control class, so why cast it at all, just set c.Enabled = enable, unless there are other reasons?

Comment: By the way, I'll assure you that using reflection to do this is going to be a lot more verbose. If you need to cast, you've already verified the type, so you should use a straight cast, not the "as" operator since it has additional overhead.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great example of when *not* to use reflection.

The `Control` class contains an `Enabled` property that you can use for all descendants of `Control` to change their enabled state.  So the simple way to change the enabled state of a collection of controls is:

```
bool enable = false;
foreach (Control c in controlList)
    c.Enabled = enable;
```

Or (now that you've mentioned the `System.Web.UI` namespace) you can do this for your `WebControl`-derived objects, assuming that the `controlList` collection can contain things that derive from `Control` but no necessarily from `WebControl`:

```
foreach (WebControl c in controlList.OfType<WebControl>())
    c.Enabled = enable;
```

Reflection is handy in some situations and you can do some pretty cool things with it.  It's verbose and kind of tough to get your head around sometimes, and often it can be done more simply other ways.

Where it would be useful is if you had a collection of arbitrary objects of different types, some of which may have a `bool Enabled` property that you can set, but that there is no guarantee that they have a common base class that you can access the `Enabled` property on.  Then you could do something like this:

```
bool enabled = false;
foreach (var obj in objectList)
{
    var tObj = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo piEnabled = tObj.GetProperty("Enabled", typeof(bool));
    if (piEnabled != null && piEnabled.CanWrite)
        piEnabled.SetValue(obj, enabled);
}
```

A lot more complex, a bit more opaque, and much, *much* slower than simply accessing the property via the `Control` parent class.

Comment: Thanks this was my initial thought but even though I am referencing System.Web.UI, it won't recognize the enabled property. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @Tom Oh, you should have specified that you were using web controls rather than form controls.  What you want then is `WebControl` rather than `Control`.  That's where the `Enabled` property is located in the `System.Web.UI` classes.  If you go to the MSDN page for any of the controls you are using and show all the inherited properties it will tell you which base class it inherits that property from.